# Select all from column family not returning all

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm having inconsistent results when I attempt to select * from a column family. For fun, I ran the same query in a loop and then counted the result set returned. No matter what I do, it seems to vary (sometimes as much as +/- 150 rows for every ~4,000).

`rSet = session.execute(SimpleStatement('SELECT * FROM colFam', consistency_level=ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM))`

Using this query results in different row counts returned. The table in question isn't going to hold millions of rows - being able to accurately select * from it is important. Running the query directly in CQLShell yields similar weirdness.

Is there something inherent in CQL/Cassandra that I haven't yet learned about that prevents Cassandra from being able to return an accurate representation of *? Or is my Google fu just failing me?

Comment: What replication factor does your table have? How many nodes do you have in cluster? Have you tried to run `nodetool repair` on this table?

Comment: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/

Comment: @shutty, appreciate the tips. I'm still investigating, but also went through with an upgrade. So far, my repairs seems to actually be doing something.

 jny my question had nothing to do with how to count rows returned.